# How __ATTR macro is used in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, sysfs

I would like to create a sysfs entry, which is done using an "attribute" structure. The way recommended to do this is to use the __ATTR macro, as in this:

```
static ssize_t functionCalledOnRead(struct kobject *, struct attribute *, char *);
static ssize_t functionCalledOnRead(struct kobject *, struct attribute *, char *);

static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name, S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR, functionCalledOnRead, functionCalledOnWrite);
```

However, this does not work.

```
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: warning: braces around scalar initializer
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: warning: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.name')
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: error: field name not in record or union initializer
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: error: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.name')
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: error: field name not in record or union initializer
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:15: error: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.name')
In file included from include/linux/thread_info.h:11:0,
                 from include/asm-generic/preempt.h:4,
                 from arch/arm/include/generated/asm/preempt.h:1,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:59,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:2:
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.name')
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: error: unknown field 'show' specified in initializer
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.mode')
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: error: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute.mode')
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: error: unknown field 'store' specified in initializer
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
include/linux/bug.h:34:45: warning: (near initialization for 'genericSysfsAttribute')
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^
include/linux/kernel.h:842:3: note: in expansion of macro 'BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO'
   BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO((perms) & 2) +     \
   ^
include/linux/sysfs.h:102:12: note: in expansion of macro 'VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS'
    .mode = VERIFY_OCTAL_PERMISSIONS(_mode) },  \
            ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:49: note: in expansion of macro '__ATTR'
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                                                 ^
/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.c:32:25: warning: 'genericSysfsAttribute' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static struct attribute genericSysfsAttribute = __ATTR(attr_name,S_IRUGO | S_IRUSR,functionCalledOnRead,functionCalledOnWrite);
                         ^
scripts/Makefile.build:297: recipe for target '/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule/sysfsmodule.o] Error 1
Makefile:1425: recipe for target '_module_/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/osboxes/Documents/kernel_modules/sysfsmodule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/osboxes/Documents/linux-mykonos'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'cross' failed
make: *** [cross] Error 2
```

I don't really understand what most of these errors are saying since they're talking about included code and not what I wrote. However, since the first argument is just a name and the second is just a number, I don't expect there is anything wrong with those, so it seems like its something to do with how I am giving the names of those two functions isn't working. How does one pass a function like this?

Answer (score 0):

Macro `__ATTR` is not for direct use, but for use by *subsystem* developers who defines type for [kobject](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kobject.txt) and creates attributes structure "derived" from `struct attribute`.

Also, plain `struct attribute` has [a little sence](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt):

> A bare attribute contains no means to read or write the value of the
>   attribute. Subsystems are encouraged to define their own attribute
>   structure and wrapper functions for adding and removing attributes for
>   a specific object type.

Answer (score 0):

The error arises due to the value of the mode you are passing to the macro, i.e. `S_IRUGO|S_IRUSR`. In the `<linux/kernel.h>` module, permission check raises an error if the permissions violate any of the following:

1. USER_READABLE >= GROUP_READABLE >= OTHER_READABLE
2. <777 and >0
3. USER_WRITABLE >= GROUP_WRITABLE
4. OTHER_WRITABLE = 0 (not a good idea to allow writes here)